# how to use Magento2 token

Tags: magento2, php

How can i use authentication token in magento2 API? 
because the dynamic generated token not working and giving a permission error and if i use the same token as static then it works. But there is one more issue that i can't use it for long because it is getting expire

I want to update inventory using API in magento2.3 and for that we need to pass token

I am using rest/V1/integration/admin/token for token and passing in rest/V1/inventory/source-items

please guide